# How can I deactivate certain mouse buttons?

Tags: mouse

I accidentally click on [these buttons](http://i.cubeupload.com/nBIRU2.jpg) on the side of my mouse. How can I deactivate these 2 buttons using Ubuntu MATE?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mouse like that, but I know it's different from windows, try this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations). Hope it can help you.